# How to filter django model based on other non related model

Tags: python, django

Please refer to the code below

Transaction models

```
class Transaction(models.Model)
    current_product_code = models.CharField(....)
    previous_product_code = models.CharField(....)
    @property
    def status(self):
        c_price = Product.objects.get(code=self.current_product_code).price
        p_price = Product.objects.get(code=self.previous_product_code).price
        if c_price == p_price:
            return "Due"
        elif c_price > p_price:
            return "Upgrade"
        else:
            return "Downgrade"
```

Product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(....)
    price = models.DecimalField(....)
```

My question: How can i obtain/filter transactions with upgrade/downgrade/due status. I am trying to create a custom admin filter which filter transaction based on their status but i fail what to put inside .filter() , check the method below

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    value = self.value()
    if value == 'Upgrade':
        return queryset.filter(***** HERE *****)
    elif value == 'Downgrade':
        return queryset.filter(***** HERE *****)
    elif value == 'Unknown':
        return queryset.filter(***** HERE *****)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use `ForeignKey` between `Product` and `Transaction` (for both: `current_product_code` and `previous_product_code`). This will allow you to use those relations in your querysets with ease.

My proposed models structure looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(....)
    price = models.DecimalField(....)


class Transaction(models.Model)
    # You have to define related_name for at least one of relations below.
    # Without that, automatically generated ones will clash.
    # Also don't foget to change `on_delete` to suit your needs.
    current_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="current_transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    previous_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="previous_transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def status(self):
        # also, no need to do additional queries here manually. You can improve
        # it further by using `select_related` when querying for transactions.
        c_price = self.current_product.price
        p_price = self.previous_product.price
        if c_price == p_price:
            return "Due"
        elif c_price > p_price:
            return "Upgrade"
        else:
            return "Downgrade"
```

With that model structure, finding specific types of transactions will be easier:

```
upgrade_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(current_product__price__gt=F('previous_product__price'))
downgrade_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(current_product__price__lt=F('previous_product__price'))
due_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(current_product__price=F('previous_product__price'))
```

Comment: I am working on live project, how can i deal with prevois transactions with old data?

Comment: You can create migrations to change your DB structure. Basically, you will need 3 migrations: 1st will add new columns for foreign keys (with null=True, so you can leave them empty for now) and change old columns to add null=True to them. The second one should fill in new columns (it is nice to include also reverse code in them to fill in old columns when you're reversing it), the third one should remove old columns and make foreign keys non-nullable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try to use [`Subquery`, `OuterRef`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) and `.annotate()`:

```
if value == 'Upgrade':
    return queryset.annotate(
        previous_price=Subquery(
            Product.objects.filter(
                code=OuterRef("previous_product_code")
            )[:1]
        ),
        current_price=Subquery(
            Product.objects.filter(
                code=OuterRef("current_product_code")
            )[:1]
        ),
    ).filter(current_price__gt=F("previous_price"))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that filter() operation, in the end, is a SQL operation and we should take care on the performance issues.

So my advice is: if you need to filter by status, update the status on Product model everytime a transaction is saved. Your application will be faster and will have a cleaner code.